# JSON Path throwing file not found exception even when configuration is set to Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a JSON input as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Test",
    "location": {
      "address": "Street 1",
      "crossStreet": "Street 2"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Test"
  }
]
```

where the `location` information is optional.

So I have set `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` to my JSONPath configuration variable. However, I am still getting path exceptions when I try to access `address` field in `location`.

Below is my code snippet:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration();
conf = conf.addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL);

String JSONString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(inputObject);
DocumentContext conT = JsonPath.parse(JSONString , conf);

String daddress = conT.read("$[1].location.address", String.class);
```

How to make it optional? For example, if the path is invalid then just assign null to my variable `daddress`.